# Is there a way to perform AJAX calls in switch statements that doesn't violate DRY?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a select form with three options at the moment and depending on what the user chooses, an AJAX call is sent out to a certain URL.  This is my code at the moment:

```
$("#Option").on("change", function(){
   $choice = $(this).val();
   switch($selection) {
   case "A": 
       $("form").submit(function(){
           //ajax call
       }
       break;
   case "B": 
       $("form").submit(function(){
           //ajax call
       }
       break;
   case "C": 
       $("form").submit(function(){
           //ajax call
       }
       break;
   }
   default: 
    //default
});
```

While this works, I feel like there is a more concise way to go about doing this rather than repeating the AJAX calls and only changing the URL's.

Comment: What changes between the AJAX calls? That's the important part thats missing here. Also, your selector is missing a closing quote.

Comment: If you're only changing the URLs, why not create a function with a `url` parameter and simply call that?

Comment: You're missing a `);` at the end of each `case` clause.

Comment: don't do this. Assigning event handlers in another event handler (with the obvious exception of `$(document).ready`) will lead to multiple handler executions and possible errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only changing the URL, assign it to a variable. Move the form submit function and the ajax call outside the switch statement.

```
$("#Option").on("change", function(){
   $choice = $(this).val();

   var url = "";

   switch($selection) {
   case "A": 
       url = "...";
       break;
   case "B": 
       url = "...";
       break;
   case "C": 
       url = "...";
       break;
   default: 
       //default
   }

    $("form").submit(function(){
      $.ajax({
         url: url,
         // other stuff
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution creates an event listener each time the selected value changes, leading to multiple ajax calls. You can see it yourself adding an alert before of $.ajax({

Comment: a demo of what I'm saying http://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/oe5Lz32d/1/ select a different value multiple times and you'll get the same number of times the alert message.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `switch-case` inside the form `submit` event and set `url` for `$.ajax()`

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var $choice = $("#Option").val();
    var url = "";
    switch ($choice) {
        case "A":
            url = "...";
            break;
        case "B":
            url = "...";
            break;
        case "C":
            url = "...";
            break;
        default:
            //default
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        // other stuff
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what changes among the submits, eg.

If it's only the url, you can use

```
$("#Option").on("change", function(){
    $choice = $(this).val();
    $url = false;
    switch($selection) {
        case "A": 
            $url="/urlA";
            break;
        case "B": 
            $url="/urlB";
            break;
        case "C": 
            $url="/urlC";
            break;
    }
    if ($url){
        //change "action" attribute
        $("form").attr("action",$url);
        //trigger "submit" event
        $("form").trigger("submit");
    }
});
$("form").submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        method: ($(this).attr("method") || "GET");
        data: $(this).serialize();
    }).done(function(ajaxResponse) {
        console.log(ajaxResponse)
    });
});
```